# Computing the correlation between two random variables

Tags: probability, correlation

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are random variables uniformly distributed between $[0,1]$.

Further, 
$$
Y=\begin{cases}
X,& \text{ if } \quad X<\alpha\\
1+\alpha - X,& \textbf{ if } \quad X \geq \alpha
\end{cases}
$$ Compute the correlation of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: How would you try to compute the correlation? Please tell us what you have tried.

Comment: In order to compute $\rho = \dfrac{E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]}{\sqrt{E[X^2] - E[X]^2}\sqrt{E[Y^2] - E[Y]^2}}$. I can see that $E[X] = 1/2$, and can compute $E[X^2] = 1/3$, but I am unable to compute $E[XY]$.

Answer (score 1):

To compute $\mathsf{E}[XY]$, we have for $0 < \alpha < 1$,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}[XY] &= \mathsf{E}[XY \mid X < \alpha] \cdot \Pr(X < \alpha) + \mathsf{E}[XY \mid X \geq \alpha] \cdot \Pr(X \geq \alpha) \\
&= \mathsf{E}[X^2 \mid X <  \alpha] \cdot \Pr(X < \alpha) + \mathsf{E}[(1 + \alpha - X)X \mid X \geq \alpha] \cdot \Pr(X \geq \alpha) \\
&= \left(\int_0^{\alpha}\frac{x^2}{\alpha} dx\right) \cdot \alpha + \left(\int_\alpha^1 \frac{(1+\alpha - x)x}{(1-\alpha)}dx\right)\cdot(1-\alpha) \\
&= \int_0^\alpha x^2 dx + \int_\alpha^1 (1 + \alpha-x)xdx
\end{align}
It is left as an exercise for you to compute the result.